# Javascript MSI automation - closing the database

Tags: windows-installer

I'm maintaining some build scripts that munge MSI databases from Javascript files (.js). The code is basically:

```
{
    var oTargetDB = g_oInstaller.openDatabase("mymsi.msi", msiOpenDatabaseModeReadOnly);
    var oView = oTargetDB.openView(...);
    oView.execute();
    oView.close();
}
// Later...
{
    var oTargetDB = g_oInstaller.openDatabase("mymsi.msi", msiOpenDatabaseModeTransact);
}
```

The second openDatabase fails with the ever-helpful 0x80004005 (E_FAIL), which I assume is because the first one is not closed. However, the Database object has no close method. I tried oTargetDB=null - didn't change anything.

What can I do to close the database, so I can open it again?

Edit:

- I see the handle open using handle.exe from sysinternals, so it's definately the problem
- Delay didn't help (I tried waiting for a really long time, and it didn't help)
- Short-lived script isn't an option due to the existing script structure
- Uber-hacking is beyond the scope of this fix
- I'll have to uglify my code and go with the (pseudo-singleton) solution. Blergh.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the handle to null works with VB Script, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't with JS. My best guess would possibly be that you've discovered a bug in the JS implimentation - especially if you're opening it as read-only the first time, there isn't any need to call the `Commit` method to flush any changes.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369434(VS.85).aspx) seems to indicate that simply closing the handle is all that is needed to close the database. So I'm guessing even after setting oTargetDB=null Javascript isn't releasing the handle by the time you go to open it again. You could try inserting a delay after releasing the handle to see if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, MS forgot to implement a close method. Really. Lame huh? In general, setting obj=null does not perform clean up such as close operations.

When I ran into specific this problem, it was calling the MSIDatabase objects from C#. The database needs to be closed (see [MsiOpenDatabase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370338(VS.85).aspx) and [MsiCloseHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370067(VS.85).aspx)). Unfortunately, as you have observed, MS forgot to implement [Database.Close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368254(VS.85).aspx) in the COM object you see. From C#, I was able to call [Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.finalreleasecomobject.aspx) to unlock the file.

We eventially gave up on the COM object as unreliable and switched to p/invoke.

If jscript is your only option, you can keep the scripts short lived - when they die they release their handles. Or, you create a singleton to represent the object. Potentially, some uberhacker will know how to invoke MsiCloseHandle from jScript, and identify the handle used by that COM object.